# Pass a type name to a templated operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, implementation, rvalue

I know that there are questions with the same topic, but this one asks for something more specific.

I am creating a personal use multi-type templated container. The details are not important, but here are basic operators that I wanted to use with my container:

- `obj[n]` which returns its own type so that it can be used to assign values as in `obj[n]=value;` (as an lvalue)
- overloaded `obj[n]` which returns value retrieved stored in the "array" as in `something=obj[n];` (as an rvalue)

The second overloaded operator is the one I want to talk about.

Using an extremely minimal example, here's the basic look of my class:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class example
{
    /*some private and public definitions*/

    example<T1, T2>& operator[] (int n)
    {
        current = n;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename U>
    U operator[] (int n)
    {
        /*some operations*/

        return something;
    }
};
```

The problem is, I want to parametrize the return value of the overloaded operator.

I read in one question here, on stackoverflow, that it is only possible to do that by calling the operator "explicitly explicitly".

**My question is, how can I workaround this problem, so that if I can't parametrize an usual operator call, at least to implement my rvalue operator[] differently for what I want to achieve to be possible?**

Answer (score 1):

There are two operators that might be overloaded in your code.  The `[]` operator and the `=` operator.  You could overload `[]` to return an rvalue to a special class, and then overload `=` for that special class depending on whether that class appears on the left or right of the operator.